# What is the correct way to create custom model binders in MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to follow the steps in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) using a vNext project and mvc 6. I've been reading through the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/d00c7ef59723fa2d7d5a544b9a831b73eb397c12/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding) but still a little unsure how to implement this.

Does anyone have a working example they could share or point me in the right direction?

I'm particularly wondering how to register the custom binder, and what classes I would inherit from since DefaultModelBinder is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample model binder: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs

How to register the binder in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{ 
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options => 
    { 
        options.ModelBinders.Add(typeof(MyModelBinder)); 
    });
```

Comment: Beta5 must have changed, `Add` now requires `new MyModelBinder()`

Comment: this is no longer true, this commit replaced ModelBinders property with ModelBinderProviders property https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/fb81a5e11ead9866b2ecf6851168230b44327085

Answer (score 1):

I have made a blog post that contains sample of trimming strings automatically in the model.

Blog post is here http://hotzblog.com/asp-net-vnext-defaultmodelbinder-and-automatic-viewmodel-string-trim/

I noticed that adding directly to model binders won't work totally, because model binders are used in order. You will have to first remove the original model binder

```
  services.AddMvc().Configure(options =>
  {
       // Replace MutableObjectModelBinder with extended Trimmer version
       IModelBinder originalBinder = options.ModelBinders.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(MutableObjectModelBinder));
       int binderIndex = options.ModelBinders.IndexOf(originalBinder);
       options.ModelBinders.Remove(originalBinder);
       options.ModelBinders.Insert(binderIndex, new TrimmingModelBinder());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of the `MVC 6` `RC1` custom `Model Binder` though I must admit that it's not perfect yet. For some reason the `getters` of the `ViewModel` are getting hit before the values are bound to them, so we have to add `if (xID == 0)` checks, which is lame... and I'm still looking for a solution, anyways, this should help out some:
https://github.com/Serjster/IOCModelBinderExample

Feel free to contribute if you happen to find a solution.