# mvc6 custom model binder not firing

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, custom-model-binder, imodelbinder

I'm trying to figure out model binding in current mvc6 (visual studio 2015 release candidate).
This is what my code looks like so far:

```
public class MyObjectModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(MyObject))
        {
            var model = new MyObject();
            return Task.FromResult(new ModelBindingResult(model, bindingContext.ModelName, true));
        }
        return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(null);

    }
}
```

The registration in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinders.Add(typeof( MyObjectModelBinder));
    });
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ReceiveMyObject([FromBody] MyObject x)
{

}
```

I don't care yet about actually creating the object from the input, what troubles me is that when I debug, I see the controller firing (with x being null), but the binder function is not being called.
Any ideas of what's wrong here?

[EDIT: This has already been updated]Also note, I have already seen [What is the correct way to create custom model binders in MVC6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448198/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-custom-model-binders-in-mvc6?rq=1) but the answer in that post is either wrong or outdated, since the example provided doesn't implement the current IModelBinder.

Thanks

EDIT: This is the javascript code used to fire the controller:

```
function sendMessage(i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { console.log(data) }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
public void ReceiveMyObject([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyObjectModelBinder))] MyObject x)
```

to method or u can set default binder for type

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[FromBody]` decoration on the action's parameter.

`FromBody` is indicated that an `InputFormatter` is to be used to populate this parameter. If you remove it model binders run.

Comment: If I remove it, the controller no longer fires. It does if there is no parameter, though. I've attached the javascript I use for testing, but in the real case the call is being made by an external software, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add it as the first model binder into the list.
When an `IModelBinder` successfully sets a model, other `IModelBinder` won't be fired.

So if you want to give a chance to your own `IModelBinder` you have to make it being fired before others do the job.

This works for me:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new MyObjectModelBinder());
});
```

But index `0` is not the best place to put it. Just determine which ModelBinder sets the model and prevents your ModelBinder to be fired and put your ModelBinder before it.