# ModelState for Model inside Viewmodel is not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view model as shown below

```
public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public Model1 Property1 { get; set; }
    }

public class Model1
{
    [Required]
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

In View We have

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Model1.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Model1.Name)
```

In Controller we have

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     Model1 a= new Model1();
     SampleViewModel s= new SampleViewModel();
     s.Property1=a;
     return View(s);
}
```

When Name is null ModelState is not getting populated with model errors even though I have Required attribute for Name. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have `public A Model1 { get; set; }` and not `public Model1 A { get; set; }`?

Comment: @Jay: Add more code to show what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you should at least create some `<input>` tag. For example to use the `Html.TextBoxFor()`:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property1.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property1.Name)

<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1.Name)</p>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit " />
```

The problem can be discovered if you look at the HTML generated by the MVC. The `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1.Name)` is rendered to the following markup:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Property1_Name" name="Property1.Name" type="text" value="" />
```

With the `data-val-required` attribute the posted page is validated correctly and the `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` when no data entered.

Or you can use:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property1.Name)
```

---

Similar problem is described here: [Required string attribute with null value gives IsValid=true in ASP.NET Core 2 Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47118980/6630084)